# How to use ng-if condition with enums? (angular2/typescript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, enums

I have one view and in this view 3 buttons:

```
showListOne()

showListTwo()

showListThree()
```

when each of this buttons is being clicked i want to present a different list, at the same view but not at the same time (only one list will be presented at a time, like tabs behaviour).

So I thought doing it with enums, this is how:

export enum CurrentListView {People, Cars, Places}

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [require('./my-app.css')],
  directives: [DND_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [DND_PROVIDERS],
  template: require('./my-app.component.html')
})

  @Injectable()
  export class AppCmp implements OnInit {

    listOfPeople: Person[];
    listOfCars: Car[];
    listOfPlaces: Place[];

    currentListView: CurrentListView;

    constructor(private _MyService: MyService) {
    };

    public showListOfPeopleData(): void {
      this.currentListView = CurrentListView.People;
    }

    public showListOfCarsData(): void {
      this.currentListView = CurrentListView.Cars;
    }

    public showListOfPlacesData(): void {
      this.currentListView = CurrentListView.Places;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this._MyService.getListOfPeopleData().subscribe(res => {
        this.listOfPeople = res;
      });

      this._MyService.getListOfCarsData().subscribe(res => {
        this.listOfCars = res;
      });

      this._MyService.getListOfPlacesData().subscribe(res => {
        this.listOfPlaces = res;
      });
    }
  }
```

Now, How do I use ng-if to ask what is the state of `currentListView`? this is my view (the ng-if there is what i tried and it dosent work):

```
<div *ngIf="currentListView == CurrentListView.People">
    <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOfPeople">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#person of listOfPeople; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        ID: {{person.id}} <p></p> Age: {{person.age}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div *ngIf="currentListView == CurrentListView.Cars">
    <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOfCars">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#car of listOfCars; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        ID: {{car.id}} <p></p> Color: {{car.color}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div *ngIf="currentListView == CurrentListView.Places">
    <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOfPlaces">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#place of listOfPlaces; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        City: {{place.city}} <p></p> Capacity: {{place.capacity}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And can my typescript or html could be more efficient? I would love to see a suggestion to a more generic way to do this without repetition..

thanks allot!

Comment: I'd suggest doing it differently. Put each view into a component, then set up routes to each one. Your buttons become a router link that loads the respective component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can compare arrays (leave alone it is bad performance),
I suggest instead you can store the "list-to-be-showed" in some string variable
something like this:

```
    currentListView:string = 'Bikes';
```

like in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/U8z6jC?p=preview)